# Facebook FQL maximum query length for a bunch of URLs

Tags: php, facebook, url, sdk, facebook-fql

1. What is the maximum allowed length of a Facebook FQL query like this one below ($urls being the comma separeted list of youtube urls from one channel)?
   Currently for my $fql query of 62 urls, strlen returns about 5 KB, but as the video submissions come along I'm afraid I might bump into some kind of request or response limit.
   I'm using Facebook PHP SDK 3.2.0 from github.

   ```
   $fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";  
   $fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";  
   $fql .= "link_stat WHERE url IN ( $urls) ORDER BY total_count DESC";  

   $fqlResults = $facebook->api(array(  
   'method' => 'fql.query',  
   'query' =>$fql  
   ));
   ```
2. When running FQL or Graph queries to get share count of a given URL, every once in a while I end up with a URL stat having couple of likes(total_count) less than what the Like button for that identical URL states.
   I'm aware of comment,share,like aggregation in the Like button count, but I'm talking about just a couple of likes less, and with identical URL. Almost as if some likes were made private for the graph api but not for the Like button plugin.